# Material design API to extract background color

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there any API for Android that lets you extract the dominant background color to create a transparent overlay so I can write text on top of it.

For example, if the dominant color of the 4 images is brownish, the overlay is transparent brown.

I'm looking to create something like the following image to add information on top of the pictures. It was taken from Google play music.

[image: google play music]

Thank you

Comment: You should take a look at new [Palette API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/graphics/Palette.html) and [there](https://developer.android.com/training/material/drawables.html#ColorExtract) is a sum up of this API fonctionnalities

Comment: I create an answer which is a simple example of how you can use it to solve your pb ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a solution :

I assume you put 4 imageview in a RelativeLayout (called parentLyt)

```
RelativeLayout view = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.parentLyt);
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
view.buildDrawingCache();
```

You can now get a bitmap of your 4 images :

```
Bitmap bitmap = view.getDrawingCache();
```

And use Palette API over this bitmap :

```
Palette colorPalette = Palette.generateAsync(bitmap, new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
     public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {
         int color = palette.getLightVibrantSwatch().getRgb();
         // Do something with colors...just for example : 
         // Convert to hex format and add 88 alpha channel "#88RRGGBB"
         String transparentColor = String.format("#88%06X", 0xFFFFFF & intColor);
         // Convert back to Color object aka int
         int finalColor = Color.parseColor(transparentColor);
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the alpha to accomplish such transparency. So when you define a color, you normally use #RRGGBB (Red Green Blue), but you can also use #AARRGGBB, where you specify the alpha as well.
`#00RRGGBB` is fully transparent and `#80RRGGBB` is like half-transparent. You can select a color like that and use it as background.

Comment: I knew about the alpha transparancy but I was asking about a function to retreive the dominant color of the images forming the background. Then use that color as a transparant foreground for the images. Sorry if the question was unclear, I updated it.

Comment: Ok, 'dominant' makes a difference :)